# Getting the pivot points for the last nth bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

```
if barstate.islast
// Loop through the last 1000 bars
    for i = 0 to 1000
        float _pivotHigh = na
        int _leftBars = 10
        int _rightBars = 10
        int _pivotRange = ( _leftBars + _rightBars )
        float _leftEdgeValue = nz(_series[_pivotRange], na)
        if not na(_series) and _leftBars > 0 and _rightBars > 0 and not na(_leftEdgeValue)
            float _possiblePivotHigh = _series[_rightBars]
            float[] _arrayOfSeriesValues = array.new_float(0)
            for _barIndex = _pivotRange to 0
                array.push(_arrayOfSeriesValues, _series[_barIndex])
            //end for
            int _pivotHighRightBars = array.size(_arrayOfSeriesValues) - array.lastindexof(_arrayOfSeriesValues, array.max(_arrayOfSeriesValues)) - 1
            _pivotHigh := ( _pivotHighRightBars == _rightBars ) ? _possiblePivotHigh : na
        
// Plot the label when a pivot point is detected. (Nothing gets plotted)
        if not na(_pivotHigh)
            label.new(bar_index[_leftBars], _pivotHigh, text=str.tostring(_pivotHigh))
```

When we get to the end of the chart, a look-back loop to go through the last 1000 bars is implemented and the pivots for that period needs to be plotted and labelled. Currently, nothing gets plotted.